# Initial value on TextField with StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have a `TextField` rendered with the help of a `StreamBuilder`, following the `BLoC` pattern with a sink and stream.

```
Widget field(SignUpBloc signUpBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: signUpBloc.outFirstName,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return TextField(
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
          onChanged: signUpBloc.inFirstName,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
            errorText: snapshot.error
          ),
        );
      },
    );
}
```

My question is how do I set up an initial value? I've tried with the `StreamBuilder`'s `initialData` property but no text appears in the `TextField`.

Answer (score 3):

```
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController(); // make a controller, 

Widget field(SignUpBloc signUpBloc) {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: signUpBloc.outFirstName,
    initialData: YourData, // provide initial data
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      _controller.value = TextEditingValue(text: "${snapshot.data}"); // assign value to controller this way
      return TextField(
        controller: _controller,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
        onChanged: signUpBloc.inFirstName,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
            errorText: snapshot.error
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Edit: To put the cursor at the end of the line, you can use

```
var cursorPos = _controller.selection;
if (cursorPos.start > _controller.text.length) {
  cursorPos = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: _controller.text.length));
}
_controller.selection = cursorPos;
```

[Source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11416#issuecomment-373635441)

Comment: I've tried using a TextEditingController, as you showed in your answer but it has some side effects. For example the cursor always goes to the left most position after you type a character. It does not display all characters once typed and it also displays null if I delete all of the characters. It's hard to explain with words, if you could try it on your local environment or maybe I can update my question with a gif.

Comment: Seems an awful lot of code for just adding an initial value to the stream. I haven't tried yet your updated solution, but I'm sure it will work.

Comment: Yes, it will work and agreed it is a lot of code, probably the team will be working on adding a little less lines of code solution. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You will have to have a TextEditingController when you need to pass initial values. Using the value.copyWith strategy there is no need to deal with the cursor, and to make the widget cleaner you can pass the text controller as a parameter.

```
// Stream widget
Widget field(SignUpBloc signUpBloc, TextEditingController _txtController) {
    return StreamBuilder(
    stream: signUpBloc.outFirstName,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      _txtController.value =
          _txtController.value.copyWith(text: snapshot.data);
      return TextField(
          controller: _txtController,
          onChanged: signUpBloc.inFirstName;
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
            errorText: snapshot.error
          ),
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this issue... you must confirm that the data has fetched and passed through the builder method

```
    if(snapshot.hasData){
        return TextField(
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
          onChanged: signUpBloc.inFirstName,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
            errorText: snapshot.error
          ),
        );
     } else {
        return Container();
     }
```